# How can I fix "ImportError: cannot import name 'printmsg'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

When building an apk using buildozer I am getting the error that boils down to getting the error calling automake w/o arguments:

```
$ automake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/automake", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('automake==0.1.3', 'console_scripts', 'automake')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2352, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/automake/cli.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utils import printmsg
ImportError: cannot import name 'printmsg'
```

I already reinstalled automake. and here are the relevant versions:

```
$ sudo pip install automake
Requirement already satisfied: automake in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from automake) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: watchdog in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from automake) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from watchdog->automake) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: argh>=0.24.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from watchdog->automake) (0.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pathtools>=0.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from watchdog->automake) (0.1.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0.1.3 release of the project you are using is simply broken. It can't work because it's `cli` module assumes that the directory of the `automake` package is itself on the Python path and so `automake.utils` can be imported as `utils`.

On your system, instead of throwing an `ImportError`, that `from utils import printmsg` line has found a different top-level `utils` module elsewhere. It doesn't matter what was found, or where, because it is not the correct module.

The author did [commit a partial fix for this problem](https://github.com/gchlebus/automake/commit/49008248e459e7f7392e9b7036a095a24c43f628) but apparently missed the `automake/cli.py` file when they did this. You could manually repair it (replace `from utils` with `from .utils` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/automake/cli.py`).

If you were looking for the [GNU automake tool](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), then you don't want this Python project.  Given that you are building a Kivy APK, you are *almost certainly* looking for the GNU project, not this one.

After filing an [issue with the `automake` Python project](https://github.com/gchlebus/automake/issues/4), the author agreed their choice of name could cause conflicts and they removed it from PyPI.

Comment: Wow, reusing the name of a GNU autotool is a bad idea to say the least.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: regrettably bad. At some point the readme had you [install the command into `/usr/local/bin`](https://github.com/gchlebus/automake/commit/61c444a4bd81b0571aa823a111a7462954846445#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8), which can only further increase confusion; that location would mask the system-provided GNU automake command (installed on any Linux distribution with the build-tools package installed) or ever clobber it (on my Mac, the homebrew-provided GNU automake is installed in that very location).

Comment: Thanks, with the GNU automake I'm fine now.